# Full rank matrix multiplication delivers open image.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My apologies, my linear algebra is a bit rusty.

Suppose I have a vector $x\in O \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, where $O$ is an $m$ dimensional open set. Let $A$ be a $n\times m$ matrix with rank $n \le m$. Then does
$$
\{Ax\mid x\in O \} \subseteq\mathbb{R}^n
$$
contain an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes - by the open mapping theorem.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(functional_analysis)

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Alternatively: in finite dimensional spaces, it suffices to prove that invertible linear maps are homeomorphisms and that the quotient map $x \mapsto x + \ker A$ takes open sets to open sets.